# pretxnchangegroup hook cannot see entire changeset

Tags: mercurial

we're trying to find a way to see the entire changeset of one or more incoming revisions in a mercurial repository inside the pretxnchangegroup hook. We use version 1.6.3.

We can get the first incoming change with $HG_NODE, but `hg tip` still points to the oldest, committed change, not to the one that we're about to tack on. The same for hg `log -rNode:`

We cannot even seem to get the diff of $HG_NODE in this hook, hg log just says "unknown revision"

It seems like this is related to http://groups.google.com/group/mercurial_general/browse_thread/thread/9321b94b08ab04b9

Has anyone had the same problem and solved it somehow?

Comment: I'll go for an answer below I think your terminology is a little off.  You're trying to "see the entire changegroup" which is made up of many changesets.  $HG_NODE points to a changeset.

Answer (score 1):

It should definitely be the case that both `tip` and `log` reflect the post-arrival information.  Are you sure that the directory in which you're running those commands is that of the repository triggehg clone hooktest hooktest-clone
ring the hook?  The only way I could see that not being the case were if you were using `hg -R`, which you'd know.

Here's a test script you should be able to paste into a (unix or cygwin) shell:

```
hg init hooktest
echo this >> hooktest/afile
echo -e '[hooks]\npretxnchangegroup = hg log && hg tip' >> hooktest/.hg/hgrc
hg -R hooktest commit -A -m 'initial commit'
hg clone hooktest hooktest-clone
echo more >> hooktest-clone/afile
hg -R hooktest-clone commit -m 'second commit'
hg -R hooktest-clone push
```

When I paste that I get:

```
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %    hg init hooktest
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     echo this >> hooktest/afile
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     echo -e '[hooks]\npretxnchangegroup = hg log && hg tip' >> hooktest/.hg/hgrc
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     hg -R hooktest commit -A -m 'initial commit'
adding afile
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     hg clone hooktest hooktest-clone
updating working directory
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     echo more >> hooktest-clone/afile
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     hg -R hooktest-clone commit -m 'second commit'
ry4an@hail [~/hg] %     hg -R hooktest-clone push
pushing to /home/msi/ry4an/hg/hooktest
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
changeset:   1:ab2cec57f878
tag:         tip
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an@msi.umn.edu>
date:        Wed Nov 03 09:10:40 2010 -0500
summary:     second commit

changeset:   0:30db2e527437
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an@msi.umn.edu>
date:        Wed Nov 03 09:10:39 2010 -0500
summary:     initial commit

changeset:   1:ab2cec57f878
tag:         tip
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an@msi.umn.edu>
date:        Wed Nov 03 09:10:40 2010 -0500
summary:     second commit

ry4an@hail [~/hg] %
```

Where you can see that both 'hg log' and 'hg tip' show the new changeset in the hook.

Does that test run for you?

Comment: Turns out it has to do something with which path the repo is cloned. It seems to work fine if I clone ssh://someserver//some/absolute/path but ssh://someserver///some/absolute/path does not. For some reason we thought that we need tree slashes.

Comment: Yeah, three slashes would be wrong, but I also would have thought harmless.  So is this working for you entirely now?  If not what specifically doesn't?